# Using C++ interface in delphi/pascal

Tags: c++, delphi, interface, delphi-7, pascal

I have the following interface defined in a dll:

```
class TestInterface
{
   public: int foo(int)=0;
};
```

And the following functions let's me create objects of this type:

```
extern "C" declspec(dllexport) TestInterface* __stdcall CreateInterface();
```

The interface is implemented in the dll and I can use it in C++ without any problems (I've also defined the `.def` file to make sure everything works correctly). However when it comes to using it in pascal I have problems.
Here's how I'm trying to use the `Interface` in pascal:

```
type
  myinterface = interface(IInterface)
    function foo(param1: Integer): Integer;
  end;

TMyInterface = ^myinterface;
pCreateInterface = function: TMyInterface; stdcall;

var
  CreateInterface: pCreateInterface;
```

Using interface in pascal:

```
function init()
begin
  DllHandle := LoadLibrary(DLLPath);
  if DllHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    @CreateInterface := GetProcAddress(DllHandle, 'CreateInterface');
    if (@GetXYZ <> nil) then
    begin
      dllInitialized := true;
      myXYZ := CreateInterface();
      myXYZ.foo(1); // Access violation error here
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Everything seems to be good. When debugging, `CreateInterface` executes successfully and there is some value in `myXYZ`. But when I try to call `foo` I get access violation error.
I've noticed I can call functions that are not within any class from a dll but not those that are inside class/interface.
Am I doing something wrong? How can I do this?
Is there a way I can use a C++ dll in delphi without changing C++ source?

Comment: You might be able to declare it as a record and make it work. It's not an interface. Remember that in C++ class and struct are essentially the same thing. However, you shouldn't export classes from DLLs. It's no different from exporting classes from Delphi DLLs. You are forcing the user to use the same compiler as you.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I thought COM-like interfaces were supposed to work across all languages. Is that not true?

Comment: That's not a COM interface.

Comment: You're right, I was mistaken. Is there a way I can use a C++ dll in delphi without changing C++ source?

Comment: You can't even use C++ classes exported out of a DLL from C++ unless you have the same compiler and share a runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, your Delphi code has an object derived from IInterface, and your C++ doesn't.

But, I'd suggest you read this article, by Rudy Velthuis:-

http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-cppobjs.html

Basically, you either need to implement the C++ end as a COM object, or 'flatten' your C++ objects into C callable functions.